# Error On Setup Cron Job On Cpanel

Tags: error-handling, cron, jobs

I Try To Setup The Cron Job To My Cpanel On My Servers But It Give me An Error:
The cron Job link is:

```
*/10 * * * * wget -O schedule http://ptcpt.publiadds.org.pt/backend/scheduled.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The Error 
"-":4: bad command
errors in crontab file, can't install.